# stat_smooth SE not printed

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm

I am trying to plot a logistic curve for my data using geom_smooth(), but the SE band does not come out. The code is as follows:

```
ggplot(data = glmmdata3, mapping = aes(x = days_cnt2, y = kuni))+
geom_point()+
geom_smooth(method = "glm", method.args = list(family = binomial(link = "logit")), se = TRUE)
```

The curve itself DOES come out, but not the SE band. My data is rather big (825,386 cases), and I'm wondering if that caused this problem. Or is it because the SE is too wide? I would appreciate any inputs.

EDIT: My dataset looks like this (825386 obs. of  11 variables) :

```
        id kuni kaiki ul meet goo meetid      morph morphid days days_cnt2
1 m0000001    0     1  u    b  10      1   国務大臣       1  143     -1.82
2 m0000002    0     1  u    b  10      1       国会       2  143     -1.82
3 m0000003    0     1  u    b  10      1       国庫       3  143     -1.82
4 m0000004    0     1  u    b  10      1 国庫負担金       4  143     -1.82
5 m0000005    0     1  u    b  10      1   国庫補助       5  143     -1.82
6 m0000006    0     1  u    b  10      1       国有       6  143     -1.82
```

Comment: I see. Exactly how can you calculate the intervals and plot them on ggplot?

Comment: There are several options to calculate the intervals: It might be sufficient to use the SEs, construct intervals assuming a normal distribution and apply the inverse link function. Or you could bootstrap them.

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with your code. We would need to see your data to see what's going on here. Could you edit your question to include the output of `dput(head(glmmdata3))` please?

Comment: @AllanCameron You are right. There are many possible issues. It could just be that OP's standard errors are very small because of the large dataset and the band is simply not visible although it is plotted.

Comment: @Allan, thanks for your interest in my problem. I edited the question with a head() of the humongous data. Note that one of the variables includes two-byte characters.

Comment: @Roland that's a very good thought. From looking at the sample data I can't think of a better explanation. KMatsuda - if you change the geom_smooth line to `geom_smooth(method = "glm", linetype = 0, alpha = 1, fill = 'black', method.args = list(family = binomial(link = "logit")), se = TRUE)` do you still see a regression line?

Comment: @Allan Cameron  It took some time to recover from my PC crash, but now I managed to test your proposal.  Yes, I see a rather thin regression line on the plot.

Comment: In that case @Roland is correct. The thin line you are seeing _is_your SE band (that code removes the regression line leaving only the confidence band). It's just incredibly narrow due to your huge sample size.

Comment: GREAT! Thanks for solving the mystery! That makes total sense! Thanks Roland and Allan!